# Use of unassigned local variable Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Well I'm stuck at this use of unassigned local variable. I'm declaring first my variables and create my dictionary.

Below my code:

```
string berichtAantalMunten;
double[] munten = { 2,1,0.50,0.20,0.10,0.05};
Dictionary<double, int> aantalMunten = new Dictionary<double, int>();
int muntenTeller = 0;
double bedragTerug = totaalIngeworpen - prijsDrankje;
foreach (double munt in munten){
    double tijdelijkIngeworpen = totaalIngeworpen - munt;

    if (tijdelijkIngeworpen >= 0)
    {
        muntenTeller++;
        aantalMunten.Add(munt, muntenTeller);
        totaalIngeworpen = tijdelijkIngeworpen;
    }
}

if (aantalMunten.ContainsKey(2))
{
    berichtAantalMunten = aantalMunten[2].ToString() + " x € 2,00\n";
}

if (aantalMunten.ContainsKey(1))
{
    berichtAantalMunten +=  aantalMunten[1].ToString() + " x € 1,00\n";
}
```

Comment: You should give us more information about your compile error. Which line is having the error? Which variable is is complaining about?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd obviously the last one where `berichtAantalMunten` should be incremented

Answer (score 5):

It's the variable `berichtAantalMunten` that is not assigned a value in any case. You could fixy it by definitly assigning a value. For example by assigning `null` or -more approopriate- `"0"`:

```
string berichtAantalMunten = "0";
```

However, you are using the variable like  an integer with `+=` even if it is a `string`

```
berichtAantalMunten +=  aantalMunten[1].ToString() + " x € 1,00\n";
```

So maybe you want to convert it to a string at the end, after you have calculated the value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the second call on `berichtAantalMunten`:

```
berichtAantalMunten += ...
```

Since it is not sure that `berichtAantalMunten` has been set to anything yet. A solution would be to initialize it to `""`, or use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to create the text.